# NDepend: Find fields that are either a given type or use a given type in their generic parameters

Tags: ndepend

How would I go about using NDepend to not only identify `JustMyCode.Fields` that are *exactly* a given type, but also indirectly, i.e. fields like `IList<MyType>`, `IDictionary<int, MyType>`, `Lazy<T>` and all those "nice" generic variants/usages?

Is there any helper method similar to `.UsedBy(...)` available by any chance that provides such a functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query to get field typed with `String` or `Int32`:

```
let types = Types.WithFullNameIn(
   "System.String", 
   "System.Int32").ToArray()
from f in Application.Fields
where !f.ParentType.IsEnumeration &&
       f.FieldType != null &&
       types.Contains(f.FieldType)
select new { f, type =f.FieldType }
```

For now you cannot detect when a type is used in a generic parameter.

[image: Querying with NDepend fields of a given type]